# how to connect to team project using VS Code and tfs for angular project

Tags: angular, tfs

I am new to angular. I have created a project on my Visualstudio.com. I want to get it on my local system. I am using VS code. I want to use TFS not GIT
 Please explain as I  am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Visual Studio Team Services](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode) Extension for **Visual Studio Code**.

The process of installing is pretty straight forward:

1. Search for **Visual Studio Team Services** in VS Code and select to install the one by Microsoft
2. Open **File** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings**
3. Add the following lines to your **user settings**

   If you have VS 2015 installed on your machine, your path to Team Foundation tool (tf.exe) may look like this:

   `{
       "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
       "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
   }`

   Or for VS 2017:

   `{
       "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe",
       "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
   }`

   If you don't have any version of visual studio installed, then you can download **[TEE CLC](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/download/v14.114.0/TEE-CLC-14.114.0.zip)**.   See [Installation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#installation) for details.
4. Open a local folder (repository), From **View** -> **Command Pallette** ..., type **team signin**
5. Provide **user name** --> **Enter** --> Provide **password** to connect to TFS.

Please refer to below links for more details:

- [Using Visual Studio Code & Team Foundation Version Control
  (TFVC)](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2017/05/29/using-vscode-and-tfvc/)
- [Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) Support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start)
- [Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

[image]